# How to mock complex JAXB generated classes?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jaxb, mocking, mockito

I see myself currently in the need of writing tests relying on legacy code, and I have these generated model classes based on complex schemas, which leads to multiple nested levels of redirection. E.g:

```
country.getProvinces().getCities().get(0).getInhabitants().get(0).getName();
```

I checked the [Mockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) framework, and the possibility to have Deep Nested Stubs, but unfortunately it doesn´t work when Generics is involved.

Filling a test double is kind of out of the question, since the test code gets pretty soon hard to trace and maintain.

A similar but somehow different option would be to load sample files. The code does not get as messy, but the maintenance problem remains.

Am I missing some other option to the problem?

Comment: You could generate sample data, rather than maintaining test files. Currently there's nothing in your question which jumps out at me and suggests mocking.

Comment: Also check Fluent API: https://java.net/projects/jaxb2-commons/pages/Fluent-api

Comment: These look to me like value objects.  Why would you want to mock them?

Comment: Fair question, @David Wallace. Main reason to want mock them are: 1. usually values don't matter for the test, they just need to exist and not return null and 2. long and complex startup methods which lead to poor test maintainability. We may be talking easily 100 lines or more just for setting up a value which has no meaning for the test.

Comment: I've done this kind of thing myself in the past.  My experience suggests that if it would take you 100 lines to set up a value object, then it will probably take at least 150 lines to set up the right mocks to do everything you need the object to do.  Seriously, just create the object.  You could consider having a String in your test, which is either XML or JSON representing the object - that should be even easier to maintain than setting up the object directly.  But seriously, in my experience, mocking a value object nearly always turns out to be a mistake.

Comment: Will do that, then. Thanks for your insights!